# Bash : Execute command before redirection as standard input

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I would like the output of `cat` to print the contents of the file `poo.txt` and then redirect it as stdin to `echo`.  The contents `poo.txt`is the number `42`. i.e.

`echo "I eat " < cat poo.txt`

should return

`I eat 42`

Instead the shell returns

`-bash: cat: No such file or directory`

How would I do this?

Comment: I love how the guy who uses the line cat poo has a name that is making fun of IBS. Well played. And Kent has the answer down below.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

like this?

```
echo "I eat $(cat poo.txt)"
```